# Python - Generate random list of 2-dimesional float values

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate a very long list of random two dimensional coordinates (floats) between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Do you know a faster code than this (on my computer it takes about `4.1 sec` for `10**7` coordinates)?:

```
coordinates = (np.random.randint(0, 10, (10**7, 2)) / 10.).tolist()
```

For this number I can wait, but what should I do when the number of coordinates is `10**9`?

Timing for `10**7`:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit


def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return (np.random.randint(0, 10, (num_coord, 2))/10.).tolist()


def checkElapsedTime(num_runs):
    t_elapsed = np.empty(num_runs, dtype=np.float)
    for i in range(num_runs):
        t_start = timeit.default_timer()
        coordinates_2d = createCoordinates(10**7)
        t_elapsed[i] = timeit.default_timer() - t_start
        print('run: %2d, time_elapsed = %4.3f sec' % (i, t_elapsed[i]))

    print('(mean \u00B1 standard deviation): elapsed time = %4.3f sec \u00B1 %5.4f sec' % \
            (np.mean(t_elapsed), np.std(t_elapsed)))
     
checkElapsedTime(10)

run:  0, time_elapsed = 4.017 sec
run:  1, time_elapsed = 4.195 sec
run:  2, time_elapsed = 3.392 sec
run:  3, time_elapsed = 3.944 sec
run:  4, time_elapsed = 3.912 sec
run:  5, time_elapsed = 3.900 sec
run:  6, time_elapsed = 3.874 sec
run:  7, time_elapsed = 4.801 sec
run:  8, time_elapsed = 3.560 sec
run:  9, time_elapsed = 3.356 sec
(mean ± standard deviation): elapsed time = 3.895 sec ± 0.3979 sec
```

Comment: Does the output need to be a list? This conversion will impact the performance a lot.

Comment: A list requires you to wrap each and every element of the contiguous buffer in its own object. This will impact both memory and speed drastically. Numpy arrays provide you with almost all of the same interfaces as a list. What are you missing?

Comment: Also, if you are going to do that, take the minimum time, not the mean. You can have timeit run the test for you.

Comment: For such a kind of problem, try C or C++ compiled with -O2; you may have a gain of x200.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Thank you and Kevin, you are both right, I can work directly with numpy arrays and that would be about 10 times faster.

Comment: @Edouard Thiel: Yes that could be, but I wanted to know what is possible only by using Python and its standard libraries.

Comment: @EdouardThiel. Given that numpy is C code compiled with decent optimization, you will likely get only marginal benefit from reducing the python portion of the overhead.

Comment: Not sure on what context you are using ```createCoordinates``` in. But in this particular scenario it will be faster to only allocate one array before doing the for-loop and specifying the ```out``` keyword for the ```np.random.randint``` method. This will prevent intermediary buffer allocations.

Comment: Are you only interested in optimizing the ```createCoordinates``` function call? Otherwise you could vectorize the for-loop or just generate all random values at once by setting the appropriate size.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can do almost 2x better than just dropping the `tolist` using the new API.

Comment: @EdouardThiel. I doubt you can write a proper RNG to go even 50% faster than the answer I've posted.

Comment: note that `np.random.uniform(0, 1, size)` is about twice as fast as using `randint(0, 10, size)/10`

Comment: @SamMason. I noticed that. But it does something very different. Take a look at the domain of my choice-based solutions. I was thinking the same thing as you when I started answering this.

Comment: I'm used to make heavy computation in my research field (imagery and optimization); I like to start with python, but when the computations start to be long I reprogram it in C++, and in my experience I can have a speedup from 20x to 200x (with -O2). It's impressive. Just give a try, it's worth it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major inefficiency in your code is calling [`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html). On my machine, removing this call reduces runtime from 2.3 sec on an array of shape `(10**7, 2)` to 386ms. This is a 6x improvement. To understand why, imagine what happens when you call `tolist`: you are taking a contiguous block of memory, and individually allocating an entire `float` object for each element. This takes time, and probably at least triples your memory consumption.

Aside from being appendable, lists offer the same sequence interface as numpy arrays. In fact, lists are limited in how you can index them. You can only get one element at a time from a list, while numpy lets you do that as well as construct slices cheaply without copying data.

```
def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return np.random.randint(0, 10, (num_coord, 2)) / 10.0
```

Instead of dividing integers by 10, you can generate the numbers you want directly using [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), but this is a bit slower than the division (411ms on my machine):

```
z = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 10, endpoint=False)  # Pre-compute this outside the function
def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return np.random.choice(z, (num_coord, 2))
```

You can really speed things up by using the new [generator API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html). In this case, using [`Generator.integers`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.integers.html) and [`Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) produces identical timings on my machine, ~224ms for an array of shape `(10**7, 2)`:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return rng.integers(1, 10, (num_coord, 2)) / 10.0
```

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
z = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 10, endpoint=False)

def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return rng.choice(z, (num_coord, 2))
```

All things considered, you can achieve a speedup of approximately 10x by using the API correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comparison of faster solutions:

a) and b) are from Mad Physicist

a)

```
def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return np.random.randint(0, 10, (num_coord, 2))/10.
```

gives:

```
(mean ± standard deviation): elapsed time = 0.337 sec ± 0.0031 sec
```

b)

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
z = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 10000, endpoint=False)

def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return rng.choice(z, (num_coord, 2))
```

gives:

```
(mean ± standard deviation): elapsed time = 0.232 sec ± 0.0050 sec
```

c) FASTEST

```
def createCoordinates(num_coord):
    return np.random.random_sample((num_coord,2))
```

gives:

```
(mean ± standard deviation): elapsed time = 0.172 sec ± 0.0043 sec
```

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Why is c) faster than b)?

Comment: Because it's doing something completely different from the other solutions. You're generating random floats continuous to 1ulp instead of the values 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ...0.8, 0.9

Comment: If that's what you want, then `np.random.rand(size=(num_coord, 2))` is probably going to be faster, and `rng.rand(size=(num_coord, 2))` even faster. But that's not what your question is asking, so I didn't look into those versions.